# reuse of strtok is giving null

Tags: c, strtok

Example code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[1024];
    char *buff, *temp, *result = NULL;
    char tok[] = " ";
    printf("enter string:\n");
    gets(str);

    buff = str;

    result = strtok(buff, tok);

    while (result != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", result);
        result = strtok(NULL, tok);
    }

    printf("\n");

    char tok1[] = " ";
    temp = str;
    result = strtok(temp, tok1);

    while (result != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", result);
        result = strtok(NULL, tok1);
    }
}
```

The above code gives the following output:

```
enter string:
Hello   how  are you
Hello
how
are
you
        
Hello
```

However, I expect the output to be:

```
enter string:
Hello   how  are you
Hello
how
are
you

Hello
how
are
you
```

Why does strtok return `NULL` after printing the first word (i.e. "hello")?
I am using another variable and also initialize it and also using another token variable. How do I get the desire result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strtok()` modifies the input string. So after the first round of tokenizing the original string `str` has been modified (since `temp` is pointing to `str`).

So take a copy of the string *before* passing it to `strtok()`.

Other improvements:

1) Don't use `gets()` which has been deprecated. Use `fgets()` instead to avoid potential buffer overflow.
2) Use `strtok_r()` as it's a re-entrant.

Comment: but i didn't used str inside strtok .. i used buff.

Comment: @user3065636: `buff` is a `char *`, which means its value is merely a pointer to the start of `str` (the memory address of the first char in `str`). So `buff` simply _points to `str`_, and so that's what `strtok` is altering here

Comment: @user3065636 As Elias mentioned it's just pointing to `str`. Declare it as `temp` as `char temp[1024];` and do `strcpy(temp, str);` after reading `str`, you'll see the difference.

Comment: Yes. `strtok_r()` is not part of ISO but is part of POSIX standard.